# How can programmatically close the palette automatically opened by the Notation package

Tags: front-end, palettes

I use `<< Notation` in my init.m to load some custom notations, but now every time I start the kernel the palette always shows up, is any way to stop that?

I tried using `NotebookClose[nb]` but I don't know how to get a handle on that palette to use for the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `Notation.m` package:

> `AutoLoadNotationPalette` is a boolean variable. If `False` then the Notation palette will not be loaded when the Notation package is loaded. If the value is undefined or `True` the Notation palette will be loaded when the Notation package loads. Other package designers can set this variable outside of the Notation package through a statement similar to `` Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False ``.

So, to prevent the palette from loading you can simply use:

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;
<< "Notation`"
```

To close an already open `Notation Palette` you can use

```
NotebookClose[Notebooks["Notation Palette"][[1]]]
```

Comment: no +1 because you didn't bother to look for an easy to find duplicate -- boo hiss -- Mr.Grouch

Comment: Mr.Wizard, fair enough:)

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

```
 Needs["Notation`"]

 findNotationPalette[nb_] := 
   If[Options[nb, WindowTitle] == {WindowTitle -> "Notation Palette"}, nb, Null]

 closeNotationPalette[] :=
   Module[{notationNB},
     notationNB = Cases[findNotationPalette /@ Notebooks[], _NotebookObject]; 
     If[Length @ notationNB == 1, NotebookClose[notationNB[[1]]], Return[$Failed]]]

closeNotationPalette[]
```